# Xamarin Forms app failing due to LiveXAML

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Xamarin Forms cross platform app has been working fine for weeks, all of a sudden I try to debug on a physical device and get the error below.  I can't find too much about it via google, does anyone have any ideas how to resolve?

```
[0:] XL: Handshake server unreachable 10.0.3.2
[0:] XL: =============== LiveXAML Important Information ===============
[0:] XL: Failed to find find a handshake server. Switching to UDP broadcast.
Make sure you have opened 53031 and 53032 ports for incoming TCP connections on your host PC.
[0:] XL: ==============================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: http://knowledge.livexaml.com/livexaml-common-issues/

Also make sure your computers and mobile devices are connected to the same local network.

Comment: Important for the extension to be installed

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of this is a firewall on your machine is blocking the connection.

Also make sure the Visual Studio extension is installed. You can check to see if the handshake server is started by seeing if xlserver.exe is running while you are debugging the app.

Answer (score 0):

Go to task manager and make sure the xslserver.exe is running. If it is not, you can close restart your simulator and the xslserver.exe will usually start running.